# Вывод списка файлов в строковый массив без использования WinAPI и создания файлов

Tags: файлы, fortran

Здравствуйте, уважаемые пользователи форума.

У меня возник вопрос: как осуществить вывод списка файлов в папке в строковый массив для дальнейшей работы с ним?

При этом вариант нужен кроссплатформенный, поэтому использование WinAPI и других библиотек, работающих только с определенными ОС, не подходит.

Также нельзя создавать любые файлы, даже временные, поэтому оператор System также не могу применить.

Думал о возможности применения препроцессора, но так как в программировании не так давно, не могу понять, как его правильно использовать - в идеале хотел использовать kernel32, если программа сможет его найти - то есть на Windows, и стороннюю библиотеку на Linux. Хотя ещё на разобрался, как препроцессор вообще подключается.

Также рассматривал вариант подключения файлов C к проекту, но пока также не разобрался как фортрановские и файлы C присоединять друг к другу и вместе компилировать.

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, если у вас есть идеи, как это можно реализовать.

Работаю с интеловским компилятором 2016, а на линуксе скорее всего будет gcc.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Использование WinAPI все равно будет под капотом.

Comment: Согласен, просто я не знаю как использовать препроцессор, чтобы на Windows нормально подключался WinAPI, а на Linux текст с WinAPIшными функциями и с подключением самой библиотеки просто не компилировался. Иначе просто выбросит из проги, сказав что не найдена библиотека.